# How to recognize a C# class as an instance of ArrayOf

Tags: c#, arrays, reflection, types

apologies if this a naive question. I have written a "universal" C# Web service client: it works by examining the WSDL of any Web service, and generating a Windows Forms UI that allows you to submit requests to the Web service and display responses.

It generates the UI as follows: first, it dynamically generates a compiled assembly (using ServiceDescriptionImporter and CodeCompiler) from the Web service's WSDL, and then it introspects on the SoapHttpClientProtocol client generated by this process.

For each Web service method, the UI to display the input parameter fields is generated by reflecting on the parameter types. Essentially, I have to recognize each type and decide how best to display it (so a String parameter is displayed as a textbox, a Boolean as a checkbox, and so on).

The types I'm having difficulty recognizing are types such as ArrayOfKeyValuestringstringKeyValueOfstringstring. I could simply parse the name of types ( along the lines of if (name begins with "ArrayOf")), but I'm sure there must be a better way to recognize these types as being arrays in some way.

If anyone can suggest how to do this, I'd be most grateful! Thanks, Martin

Comment: Can you provide some sample content. The SOAP XML or portion of the code illustrating the problem. I found some SOAP documentation that seems to indicate that the XML explicitly identifies array I don't know if that helps: http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383522

Comment: Is the type literally called `"ArrayOfKeyValuestringstringKeyValueOfstringstring"`?  Or is it actually an array?  So in other words, do you want to know if an object is actually an array?

Comment: Hi - yes, the type is literally called that. On the Web service side, the type is declared as a Dictionary<string,string>, but if my tool invokes the Web service, then the returned object is identified as being of ArrayOfKeyValuestringstringKeyValueOfstringstring type. If I test for type.IsArray, then this is false, but for my purposes, I'd like to treat it as being similar to an array, and so I need to identify as "array-like".

Comment: On the server-side the Web service is declared as follows: Dictionary<string, string> GetDictionary(); if I look at the corresponding generated client-side code, I can see: public ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstringKeyValueOfstringstring[] GetDictionary()

Answer (score 1):

If it's any type of array or list, it will implement IEnumerable, so this may get you off in the right direction:

```
if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(ArrayOfKeyValuestringstringKeyValueOfstringstring)))
{
    // ok, it's an array...
}
```

EDIT: Martin (user304582) points out that some other types like String implement IEnumerable. My assumption here is that, at this point in the code, the simple types (like String, Int32, etc) have already been tested for - and it is not one of them.

One could also use `Array` instead of `IEnumerable`, assuming ServiceDescriptionImporter generates parameters using arrays and not lists in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this does not work either because I need to programmatically extract the types of keys and values. For other, technical, reasons, I have upgraded my client to use the .Net 4.0 WsdlImporter and its related classes which generates more clearly typed code, and as a by-product avoids the use of these ArrayOf classes. Thanks for your help!